# Custom search results

Tags: 7, search

I am using drupal 7 built in search  module. In my custom content type, I have multiple products for `Industrial`,`mechanics` and `sports` categories. I need to apply search restriction on some products for my `mechanics` category. Means If `mechanics_product1`, `mechanics_product2` and `mechanics_product3` are mechanics products then I need to apply search restriction on all products for only `mechanics_product2`. Only authorize user will be only able to search this particular product.

Answer (score 3):

Try

**1. [Search configuration](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_config)**

This module has five main functions.

1. Alter the appearance of the core node search form
2. Group content types for more meaningful searching
3. Restrict search results by the content type. This is a role based restriction.
4. search results from showing individual items.
5. Alter the pager limit (aka number search item results per page).

**2. [Custom Search](https://www.drupal.org/project/custom_search)**

> This module alters the default search box in many ways. If you need to
>   have options available like in advanced search, but directly in the
>   search box, this module is for you.